# Sentence trimming and formatting in Python

Tags: python, nlp

So I want input sentences like this:

i )    "abcdef"
relation

ii )     "xyzaswdawd"
relation

upto a few thousand rows.

I want to extract the sentences (i.e the text between " " for each line). Can anyone help me with that?

(Sorry if it is a naive question I am new to Python so wanted help with this)

Comment: Did you try any code at all? Even if it did not have the correct result, it could be posted along with the question for review.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex for this:

```
import re
s = input()
print(re.findall(r'\"(.*)\"',s))
```

Would return a list of those words

Comment: yeah but is it possible to get the output as a list of sentences instead of words?

Answer (score 0):

```
mySTR = str(input("Input: "))

c=0
Res=""
for i in mySTR:
if i=='"':
    if c!=0:
        print(Res)
        break
    c=c+1
else:
    Res=Res+i
```

The following code takes a string input. It starts with a count c and we assign it a value 0.
The count looks for the number for " found in your string.

It finds the first one and increments it by one. The next time it finds a " it will enter an if statement and print the Result.

The result will be anything that isn't a " and contained between two ". We concatenate every character